# Database design - Approval work flow and version creation

Tags: database-design

I need help to design database for managing versions of book in the process of publishing book.

Three rights/user types – **Author, Reviewer, Proof Reader**. 
**Book goes from creation to approved state through these steps, Creation, Review , Proof Reading and ready for Publish.**

Every Book created will have to go through following status:
**Draft:**
Every new Book is created with status draft by author. Once user has done with changes it can be converted to status "Need Review".

**Need Review:**
Now this book will be available for users for review - Need Review.
The Book  can be ‘Approved’ or can be sent back to creator 'Needs Modification'

If **'Needs Modification'**: A new version should be created and sent to the author for modifications, the original Book should be archived
Once the Book has been updated and the user sends it for review, the status should be set to "Book Needs Modification"
The Book should again go through the entire approval cycle

**If Approved:** 
-   The status should be changed to 'Ready for Proofreading Review'
-   Book will be made available to users who are entitled for Proofreading Review

The **proofreader** should be provided the access to modify the Book.

The **proofreader** will make changes where applicable and will send the Book to the reviewer for review

If the **Reviewer** approves the Book should then be made **"Ready For Publish"**.

The **reviewer** can send it back to make copyedit changes to the copyeditor with the status "**Need** **ProofReading** **Changes**"

If set to **"Need ProofReading Changes"** the application should archive the current version, create a **new version** and set it to **current** and should get into proof reading queue.

Comment: Can you include the schema have you designed thus far and tag which RDBMS you'll be targeting?

Comment: I have not yet designed schema. We will be using MS SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Kane, thanks for quick attention

Comment: Is the book itself part of the database, or just the status indicators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the book itself, you might consider using a source control system like Subversion or Git.  That way, any modifications to the book will be saved.  You'll be able to recreate any version of the book.  The modifications themselves will be available as a history.

The rest of the information is status indicators.  You would represent state with a [state transition table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table).  A state transition table is a part of a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Based on your description, I think these are the state transitions that a book can have.

```
Draft -> Needs Review
Needs Modification -> Needs Review
Needs Review -> Needs Modification
Needs Review -> Approved

Approved -> Proofreading review
Proofreading review -> Reviewer review
Reviewer review -> Proofreading review
Reviewer review -> Publish book
```

Comment: Thanks Gilbert. But this is just example. We need to develop this for other scenarios and not books. Book is just simple example we have given. Again we need to develop this in .NET and we can not integrate our system with github or any other source control. We need to develop customized solution.